# I want to get the data from the access database to a text file in c#, i have written the following code but i am not getting any output

Tags: c#

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "select action from rvrait";
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        richTextBox1.Text = (reader["action"].ToString());
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException)
    {
    }
```

Comment: ... and what is the connection string?

Comment: is there an exception thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the missing `reader.Read()` call. After creating the OleDbDataReader you cannot start taking the content of the column in which you are interested. Initially the reader is not positioned on the first record returned by your query (if any).

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "select action from rvrait";
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if(reader.Read())
         richTextBox1.Text = (reader["action"].ToString());
    connection.Close();

}
```

In this way you move the reader on the first record and you could take the content of the column if there is a true returned by the call to Read().
This pattern has been conceived to facilitate reading more than one record.
For example...

```
List<string> listOfActions = new List<string>();
while(reader.Read())
     listOfActions.Add(reader["action"].ToString());
```

Note also that I have removed the empty try/catch. This should be Always avoided if you don't plan to do anything with the exception because if you leave in place you are effectively hiding possible errors